# Php json_decode() with eBay API

Tags: php, json, ebay-api

I am trying to decode a JSON response that I am receiving from the ebay finding API.  How can I get it to echo out the `ack` message?

Here is the json response:

```
{
   "findItemsByCategoryResponse":[
      {
         "ack":[
            "Success"
         ],
         "version":[
            "1.12.0"
         ],
         "timestamp":[
            "2013-08-23T10:12:22.085Z"
         ],
         "searchResult":[
            {
               "@count":"1",
               "item":[
                  {
                     "itemId":[
                        "121158900630"
                     ],
                     "title":[
                        "SHAMROCK SHORES, TX - MONTHLY PAYMENTS - 0 INTEREST"
                     ],
                     "globalId":[
                        "EBAY-US"
                     ],
                     "subtitle":[
                        "blocks from Lake Brownwood"
                     ],
                     "primaryCategory":[
                        {
                           "categoryId":[
                              "15841"
                           ],
                           "categoryName":[
                              "Land"
                           ]
                        }
                     ],
                     "galleryURL":[
                        "http:\/\/thumbs3.ebaystatic.com\/m\/mP-wKIofn8JI9YsMduq6eUw\/140.jpg"
                     ],
                     "viewItemURL":[
                        "http:\/\/www.ebay.com\/itm\/SHAMROCK-SHORES-TX-MONTHLY-PAYMENTS-0-INTEREST-\/121158900630?pt=Land"
                     ],
                     "autoPay":[
                        "false"
                     ],
                     "postalCode":[
                        "76801"
                     ],
                     "location":[
                        "Brownwood,TX,USA"
                     ],
                     "country":[
                        "US"
                     ],
                     "shippingInfo":[
                        {
                           "shippingType":[
                              "FreePickup"
                           ],
                           "shipToLocations":[
                              "None"
                           ],
                           "expeditedShipping":[
                              "false"
                           ],
                           "oneDayShippingAvailable":[
                              "false"
                           ]
                        }
                     ],
                     "sellingStatus":[
                        {
                           "currentPrice":[
                              {
                                 "@currencyId":"USD",
                                 "__value__":"26.0"
                              }
                           ],
                           "convertedCurrentPrice":[
                              {
                                 "@currencyId":"USD",
                                 "__value__":"26.0"
                              }
                           ],
                           "bidCount":[
                              "4"
                           ],
                           "sellingState":[
                              "Active"
                           ],
                           "timeLeft":[
                              "P0DT1H12M13S"
                           ]
                        }
                     ],
                     "listingInfo":[
                        {
                           "bestOfferEnabled":[
                              "false"
                           ],
                           "buyItNowAvailable":[
                              "false"
                           ],
                           "startTime":[
                              "2013-08-13T11:24:35.000Z"
                           ],
                           "endTime":[
                              "2013-08-23T11:24:35.000Z"
                           ],
                           "listingType":[
                              "Auction"
                           ],
                           "gift":[
                              "false"
                           ]
                        }
                     ],
                     "returnsAccepted":[
                        "false"
                     ],
                     "isMultiVariationListing":[
                        "false"
                     ],
                     "topRatedListing":[
                        "false"
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ],
         "paginationOutput":[
            {
               "pageNumber":[
                  "1"
               ],
               "entriesPerPage":[
                  "1"
               ],
               "totalPages":[
                  "631"
               ],
               "totalEntries":[
                  "631"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "itemSearchURL":[
            "http:\/\/www.ebay.com\/sch\/15841\/i.html?_ddo=1&_ipg=1&_pgn=1"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The following is my php code:

```
$url = "http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?" . 
        "OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByCategory&" . 
        "SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&" .
        "SECURITY-APPNAME=YourKeyHere&" . 
        "RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&" . 
        "REST-PAYLOAD&" . 
        "categoryId=15841&" . 
        "paginationInput.entriesPerPage=1";
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);     

$json = json_decode($output, true);

$status = $json['findItemsByCategory']['ack'];
echo $status;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findItemsByCategoryResponse` is an array, the first element of which has `ack`:

```
$status = $json['findItemsByCategoryResponse'][0]['ack'];
// -------------------------------------------^^^
```

Oddly, `ack` is also an array, so to get the text `"Success"` you'd have to dereference that, too:

```
$status = $json['findItemsByCategoryResponse'][0]['ack'][0];
// -------------------------------------------^^^-------^^^
```

Comment: For what it's worth, when I've seen JSON (or other non-XML) data structures mysteriously having single element arrays like `ack` above, it's because the data has its roots in XML.  For example this is valid: `<doc><ack>Success</ack></doc>`, and so is this: `<doc><ack>Success</ack><ack>Something else</ack></doc>`.  An XML parser does not know if in the first case `<ack>` is a single element of one of a possible array, so for consistency's sake when decoding the data, it presumes it's an array.  Lots of XML parsing libraries have options concerning assuming single elements are arrays or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $json contains the receied json response, You can use the below:

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
$status = $obj->findItemsByCategoryResponse[0]->ack;
```